# How to fit multiple Spark ml models to each partitioned subset of single Dataset/DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I want to train multiple Spark ML models at once, using each subset of single Dataset. (one partition to one model.)

How can I implement it efficiently?

Scala's loop seems not good because DAG will be much complex, but Spark's mapGroups does not work as well because Spark plan will be nested.

Abstract sample is below.

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, sex: String)

val input = spark.read.load(..).as[Person]
val someModel = SomeModel()

// loop pattern
val models1 = input.map(_.age).collect.map{
  key => 
    val subset = input.filter(row => row.age == key)
    someModel.fit(subset)
}

// mapGroups pattern
val models2 = input
  .groupByKey(x => x.age)
  .mapGroups{
    (k, v) => 
      val subset = v.toList.toDS
      someModel.fit(subset)
  }
```

Neither works well. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Hi! Have you found any solution to the above problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a long time to get this to work, but gave up. I ended up using python libraries i.e. statsmodels to get the necessary coefficients output. 
If you convert to RDD or to mapGroups method like you did, then it will work. 
I tried to run spark ml glm poisson linear regression for 700k items in 1 dataset and its took 10+ hours.
When using statsmodels in pyspark for over 2million items, it took 5 mins.